# How can I calculate the pairwise difference between multiple columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
Column_1_suffix1 ... Column_n_suffix1   Column_1_suffix2 ... Column_n_suffix2
123                  567                23                   67
```

I would like to calculate the difference in a new column for each pair suffix1 - suffix2 like this:

```
Column_1_suffix1 ... Column_n_suffix1   Column_1_suffix2 ... Column_n_suffix2 ... Column_1_diff ... Column_n_diff
123                  567                23                   67                   100           ... 500
```

I cannot do it by individually calculating the differences since the number of columns n is too large. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `split.default` to split the dataset based on the prefix of column names into a `list`, loop over the `list` and the get the difference (`-`) between the two columns

```
sapply(split.default(df1, sub("_suffix\\d+$", "", names(df1))), 
          function(x) x[[1]] - x[[2]])
```

---

Or if the columns are already in order, then an option is to subset the dataset based on the substring 'suffix1', 'suffix2' into two equally sized datasets and get the difference

```
nm1 <- grepl('suffix1', names(df1))
nm2 <- grepl('suffix2', names(df1))
df1[sub("_suffix\\d+$", "_diff", nm1)] <- df1[nm1] - df1[nm2]
```

Comment: @nhriedel not clear what you meant by `which should read so`

Comment: @nhriedel do you want to create new column names by pasteing the original columns names

Comment: I tried the second approach which worked fine. However, there remains the issue of the column names which should read something like Column_n_diff. A dplyr approach would also be very nice.

Comment: @nhriedel you meant the new column names should have `_diff` as suffix?